# When to use "is agreed"?

Tags: grammar

> The bank balance **is agreed** with the bank statement.

I think this is grammatically incorrect. It sounds a bit bothering.

> The bank balance **agrees/agreed** with the bank statement.

Does this one sound better? Anyone know which one is correct? When will we use *is agreed*? I think the subject-verb agreement is not correct in the first sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would say

> The bank balance agrees with the bank statement.

or

> The bank balance is in agreement with the bank statement

or

> The balance and statement agree with each other

"Agreed" is used where people, not things, have come to an agreement, because it means an argument or discussion has taken place resulting in agreement.